# Por que o script PHP não roda se aberto pelo pc, mas roda se aberto no localhost?

Tags: php, html, localhost

Já vou logo avisando que não estou com nenhum problema e, alias, acabei de resolver um que se refere a essa pergunta mas enfim, queria saber (por curiosidade) por que um script php não roda se eu abrir o arquivo pelo computador, mas se eu digitar o endereço de local host ele roda normalmente?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
  <META NAME="author" VALUE="Fernando Aguiar Pinedo">
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="css.css">
  <LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="favicon.ico">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="cabeçalho">
   <h1>Music Downloader</h1>
   <p>Download Your Music Here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="filterlist">
   <ul>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri; margin:5px; text-align:center;">Genre</h1>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Eletronic</li>
    <li>Pop</li>
    <li>Reggae</li>
    <li>Hip Hop</li>
    <li>Anime</li>
    <li>Video Game</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri; margin:5px; text-align:center;">Language</h1>
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Japanese</li>
    <li>French</li>
    <li>Brazilian</li>
    <li>Chinese</li>
    <li>German</li>
    <li>Spanish</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content"> <!--Conteúdo Aqui-->
   <?php
    include ("connectsql.php");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM songs";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error());
 
    if($result){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $name = $row['Song'];
   ?>
   <p><?php echo "$name"; ?></p>
   
   <?php
     }
    }
   ?>
  </div> 
  <!--Até Aqui-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Na div "content" o php nao executa direto do computador, só se for aberto pela internet digitando o endereço localhost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O `PHP` é uma linguagem `back-end*` que roda no servidor geralmente o `APACHE*`, o navegador não tem poder para interpretar esse tipo de linguagem.

**O que é apache?**
O Servidor `HTTP` Número Um na Internet,
o `Apache HTTP Server Project` é um esforço para desenvolver e manter um servidor `HTTP` de código aberto para sistemas operacionais modernos, incluindo UNIX e Windows. O objetivo deste projeto é fornecer um servidor seguro, eficiente e extensível que forneça serviços `HTTP` em sincronia com os padrões `HTTP` atuais.

> Digamos que você quer salvar sua preciosa conexão e desenvolver tudo
>   localmente. Neste caso, você precisará instalar um servidor web, como
>   o » **Apache**, e claro o » **PHP**. Você provavelmente também deseja instalar
>   um banco de dados, como por exemplo o » **MySQL**.

**O que é back-end?**

Back-end
Como o nome sugere, o desenvolvedor back-end trabalha na parte de "trás" da aplicação. Ele é o responsável, em termos gerais, pela implementação da regra de negócio.

Em uma aplicação web, este desenvolvedor, quando focado, não toca na parte visual da aplicação. Por lidar com a regra de negócio, as vezes um programador de sistemas, como de aplicações comerciais e até científicas, pode ser chamado de desenvolvedor back-end. E geralmente, nessas aplicações, este desenvolvedor trabalha um pouco com a parte visual. Por isso, para este artigo, o desenvolvedor back-end levado em conta, é o desenvolvedor de aplicações web.

Quando falamos de back-end em desenvolvimento web, nos deparamos com várias linguagens, como Go, Clojure, C#, PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, entre outras. Cada uma possui vantagens e desvantagens em relação ao uso no desenvolvimento web, bem como no mercado de trabalho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Referencias:

http://httpd.apache.org/ 
http://www.php.net/  
https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/o-que-e-front-end-e-back-end/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, apesar de não não ir direto ao ponto, explicou algumas duvidas minhas!! vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Por que o navegador não consegue interpretar sozinho uma linguagem que execute no lado do servidor. Por isso que utilizamos o `WAMP`, `XAMPP`, `Apache,` entre outros. Isso vale para qualquer linguagem que faz o `Server-Side`.